What is the name for a quote that fails to be coherent in the wider sentence?
This question is about terminology. I am requesting a name for a particular kind of badly-formed sentence that incorporates a quote, where the fault is with the manner in which the quote is incorporated into the wider sentence.
This is a sentence, quoted verbatim, from the Wikipedia article on "Operation Mongoose":

The first plan in this time frame involved an attack on the radio station Castro used to "broadcast his speeches with an aerosol spray of a chemical that produced reactions similar to those of lysergic acid (LSD)".

This is a badly formed sentence. Read literally, it means something other than the writer intended it to mean. They probably should have positioned the opening quotation mark later in the sentence, something like this:

The first plan in this time frame involved an attack on the radio station Castro used to broadcast his speeches with "an aerosol spray of a chemical that produced reactions similar to those of lysergic acid (LSD)".

Modified in this way, the quote is a single part-of-speech in the wider sentence (it is the thing with which the radio station is to be attacked). In the original, the quote seems to promise to be a single part-of-speech, but it isn't really meant that way. The original, read literally, suggests that Castro was in the habit of broadcasting his speeches and that the act of broadcasting itself was somehow accomplished with the assistance of the chemical; the CIA means to attack the radio station, but the CIA has nothing to do with the chemical; the manner in which the CIA will attack the radio station isn't specified. This is not a tenable interpretation, since a hallucinogenic chemical is not something that can be put to a use such as the one that is apparently attributed to Castro or to the radio station personnel. (You could, I suppose, relax the interpretation and interpret it not as saying that the chemical was somehow involved in the technical process of broadcasting, but instead as saying that Castro was high on the chemical when he was delivering his remarks.)
A quote doesn't have to be a single part-of-speech, I guess. Perhaps it can be a subclause in the sentence. I do not have sufficient command of the analysis of English grammar, or its terminology, to be able to completely characterise the kinds of sentence fragment that can legitimately be quotes, but as a native speaker I am convinced that the original sentence quoted above is wrong and that the failure is essentially that the quote ought to be a single part-of-speech, but it isn't.
An alternative view you could take, I guess, is that the real problem is that the quote starts midway through a part of speech: it begins part-way through the noun phrase "the radio station Castro used to broadcast his speeches".
What is the name for a quote that fails to be coherent in the wider sentence, in the manner exemplified by the original quote above?

A quote can be any part of a sentence, although style guides such as APA warn against using direct quotation when unnecessary. They should be "kept within the structure of the sentence in which they appear" which means the sentence should be grammatical if quotation marks are removed - this happens here, arguably to excess. The sentence you quote is grammatical, although the order of the clauses is confusing.

If 'broadcast his speeches with an aerosol spray of a chemical that produced reactions similar to those of lysergic acid (LSD)' was in the original script, the sentence is accurate, and your recast violates the Gricean maxim of quantity (rather like saying 'I can see a cat in the garden' when there are clearly ten). But grammatically, the original works. 'The first plan in this time frame involved an attack on the radio station Castro used to "broadcasting his speeches with an aerosol spray of a chemical that produced reactions similar to those of lysergic acid (LSD)"' is obviously ill-formed.

It is very surprising to me that anybody would disagree with my assertion that a quotation might be expected to be a single part of speech in and of itself. I would have thought that uncontroversial. @EdwinAshworth you say that my proposed alternative version "violates the Gricean maxim of quantity", but this seems a specious criticism; you could equally accuse the original of violating the maxim of relevance, since it's the characterisation of the chemical that is of interest here; the words "broadcast his speeches" are functional and don't add any colour to what we're being told.

As to the final sentence of your comment, I don't know from where you got that version of the sentence (the one with "broadcasting" in place of "broadcast"). Although the word "broadcasting" appears in the text of my question, there's nothing in the question to suggest that such an obviously wrong alternative wording might be considered. The final sentence of your comment is a complete non sequitur.

As to your actual question about the name for this, I doubt there's a specific term for it. It's just an example of confusing writing, and might even be considered nonsense.

It's like quoting say  << The former President of Cuba used to broadcast his speeches with an aerosol spray of a chemical that produced reactions similar to those of lysergic acid (LSD). >> (as the original) as << Castro  used to broadcast his speeches with an aerosol spray of a "chemical that produced reactions similar to those of lysergic acid (LSD)." >> Not ungrammatical, not exactly false, but infelicitous.

Isn't this just a case of misplaced quotes? I don't see why a specific term is necessary for it.
